# Error with library libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 on UNIX

Tags: java, linux, javafx, java-8

When launching a JavaFX application, the following error occurs:

> GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/amd64/libprism_es2.so: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

But at the same time, I have the libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 library installed.

> find / -name "libgdk-x11*" 2> /dev/null:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm2aL.png)

> ldd /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/amd64/libprism_es2.so:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ELX6.png)

> java version "1.8.0_181"

I don't know what should I do. I'm new to Linux

Comment: Try running `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/amd64/` before running your program.

Comment: JavaFX 8 is obsolete.  I advise a modern distribution, the use of which is documented at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/).

Comment: Thanks for help. Changing JDK version has fixed problem. It's really strange because it has worked earlier